# STS doesn't recognize build errors

Tags: compiler-errors, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have two Spring MVC projects (*B* and *C*) that depend on a common library of classes (project *A*). All three projects are open in SpringSource Tool Suite 3.2.0.RELEASE.

If I edit a method in project *A* so that all references to it need to be modified (for instance by adding a method parameter) and save its file, STS immediately shows errors for project *B* (listing the errors in the Problem view). However, the errors **remain undetected** in project *C*. When I deploy the application, runtime errors happen because of these undetected errors in *C*.

Both *B* and *C* reference *A* in <kbd>Project right click</kbd> → <kbd>Properties</kbd> → <kbd>Deployment Assembly</kbd> and <kbd>Java Build Path</kbd>.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Hard to say what is happening here.  Can you post these projects somewhere?  Might be a bug in STS or a bug in Eclipse WTP.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Unfortunately, the source is proprietary :-( STS was clean installed on a new Win7 machine a few weeks ago; the source is taken from a Subversion repository.

Comment: Well, if you can reproduce the problem in a smaller project, then we can help.  Also, take a look at your error log and post any relevant errors here.